# Displaying Firebase data in a tableview

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, tableview

I am trying to retrieve information stored in a Firebase Database, but my tableview is not displaying the information. I have tried using print functions to see if the data is being retrieved, and it shows that this is the case, but the tableview shows up as blank when I run the simulator.

I am using Xcode 11 and every tutorial that I have looked at is not working for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import FirebaseAuth

class FeedVC: UITableViewController {
    
    var currentUserImageUrl: String!
    var posts = [postStruct]()
    var selectedPost: Post!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getUsersData()
        getPosts()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    
    func getUsersData(){

        guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct postStruct {
        let firstName : String!
        let lastName : String!
    }
    
    func getPosts() {
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        databaseRef.child("profiles").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: {
                    snapshot in
                    let firstName = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["profileForename"] as? String
                    let lastName = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                        )!["profileSurname"] as? String
                    print(firstName)
                    self.posts.append(postStruct(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName))
                    print(self.posts)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                })
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell") as? PostCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        
        let nameLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        nameLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].firstName
        return cell
    }



}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Since `PostCell` is created in the storyboard within the table view it's registered and dequeued successfully. So the issue is being narrowed down to the label with tag 1. Try creating an `@IBOutlet` for the label and use that to set the text of `UILabel`.

[image: screenshot]

Then in `cellForRowAt`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell") as? PostCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    cell.firstNameLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].firstName
    return cell
}
```

Previous: You seem to have forgotten to `register` the `PostCell`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //...
    tableView.register(PostCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PostCell")
}
```

Note: If you've created `PostCell` in Xib use nib registry method.

Update: If you want to register with Nib method use:

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: <#T##String#>, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PostCell") // provide the xib file name at the placeholder
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I am pretty new to using Swift - how would I use these nib registry method?

Comment: I have implemented the code but the table view still shows up blank...

Comment: Make sure the `reuseIdentifier` is provided in the Xib file where you've created `PostCell`.

Comment: Replace the cell declaration line with this: `guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell") as? PostCell else { print("Couldn't get cell"); return UITableViewCell() }` see if you're getting something in the log.

Comment: It's not printing 'couldn't get cell' in the log

Comment: Ok good. So that means since the cell is in storyboard it's registered and dequeued successfully.

Comment: Right now my code is linked to a UITableViewController, but it won't connect outlets to this.

Comment: Check my view structure the `UILabel` should be inside the `contentView`` of `UITableViewCell` as I've shown above.

Comment: This appeared: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value @Frankenstein

Comment: It means the outlet is not connected properly. The comments seem to be getting really long. Avoid asking follow-up questions in the comments and try to avoid making silly mistakes :).